# TextInputLayout not showing hint while typing

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

I am using TextInputLayout from com.android.support:design.My problem is that when the editText gets focus, the hint is not displayed above the editText, and when the editText loses the focus after typing in it, the hint appears above the editText. I want the hint to appear above the editText when it gets focus in addition to the appearance when it loses focus.
My xml file:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/et_id"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:hint="@string/id_hint"/>
 </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

and in my gradle I am using:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
```

Thank you very much

Comment: use support:design library version 25.3.1. compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this Define style

```
<style name="TextInputLayoutLabelGrey" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
    <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/your_color</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/your_color</item>
    <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/your_color</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/your_color</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/your_color</item>
</style>
```

Your layout xml

```
  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutLabelGrey">

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:id="@+id/et_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:hint="@string/id_hint"/>
   </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `TextInputEditText` instead 
ex:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/textInputUserName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/etUserName"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/emailorPhone"
        android:imeActionLabel="@string/next"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="text" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```